# Recursively read files from sub-folders into a list and merge each sub-folder's files into one csv per sub-folder

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to work out how to use `pandas` to recursively navigate a folders sub-folders, take each file in the sub-folder and merge it into one CSV file per sub-folder.

So I have multiple files in a structure similar to the below. I want to take each sub-folder and merger its respective CSVs into one file per sub-folder. Please refer to the second illustrated folder tree. Ive not used `pandas` before but I think I'm on the right track, I'm struggling to work out the logic for each respective sub-folder. Please refer to my current code below.

*Note, Each CSV file has the same structure with regards to the columns.

**Before Merger**

```
Folder
      Sub-Folder1
               File1.csv
               File2.csv
               File3.csv
               File4.csv
      Sub-Folder2
               File1.csv
               File2.csv
      Sub-Folder3
               File1.csv
               File2.csv
```

**After Merger**

```
Folder
      Sub-Folder1
               Final.csv
      Sub-Folder2
               Final.csv
      Sub-Folder3
               Final.csv
```

**Current Code**

```
import pandas as pd

working_dir = "/dir/"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(working_dir):
    file_list = []
    for filename in files:
        file_list.append(root + "/" + filename) 
    df_list = [pd.read_table(file) for file in file_list]
    final_df = pd.concat(df_list) 
    final_df.to_csv(root + "/" + "Final.csv")
```

Currently getting the following error

`ValueError: All objects passed were None` on line `big_df = pd.concat(df_list)`

**Output Data**  after making corrections suggested by Anand S Kumar

The csv is bring formatted with a new column that is not needed or intended and the data set is being placed into the second column in its entirety.

```
    title1,title2,title3,title4
0   data1,data2,data3,data4
1   data1,data2,data3,data4
2   data1,data2,data3,data4
0   data1,data2,data3,data4
1   data1,data2,data3,data4
2   data1,data2,data3,data4
3   data1,data2,data3,data4
```

**Data Set** added as suggested by Anand S Kumar

```
title1,title2,title3,title4
13,[Group] data1,[Group] data2,data3
11,[Group] data1,[Group] data2,data3
2,[Group] data1,[Group] data2,data3
1,[Group] data1,[Group] data2,data3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is most probably that in the main directory - `Folder` (or `/dir` according to your code) , you do not have any files , so `file_list` is empty and hence `df_list` is also empty. so when you pass an empty list into `pd.concat()` , you are getting that error. Example -

```
In [5]: pd.concat([])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.concat([])

/path/to/merge.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, copy)
    752                        keys=keys, levels=levels, names=names,
    753                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
--> 754                        copy=copy)
    755     return op.get_result()
    756

/path/to/merge.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy)
    797
    798         if len(objs) == 0:
--> 799             raise ValueError('All objects passed were None')
    800
    801         # consolidate data & figure out what our result ndim is going to be

ValueError: All objects passed were None
```

---

I would suggest you should check that the files you are reading are really files and that they end with `.csv` and that the `df_list` is not empty, when you pass it into `pd.concat()`. Also I would suggest that you use `os.path.join()` , rather than concatenating strings, to create paths. Example -

```
import pandas as pd
import os.path
import os

working_dir = "/dir/"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(working_dir):
    file_list = []
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            file_list.append(os.path.join(root, filename)) 
    df_list = [pd.read_table(file) for file in file_list]
    if df_list:
        final_df = pd.concat(df_list) 
        final_df.to_csv(os.path.join(root, "Final.csv"))
```

---

**EDIT:**

As you say -

> Also the output is adding another column that looks to be an id column.

The new column that comes in is most probably the index of the DataFrames.

When doing [`DataFrame.to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) , if you do not want the index of the DataFrame to be written to csv , you should specify `index` keyword argument as `False` so that the index is not written to the csv. Example -

```
final_df.to_csv(os.path.join(root, "Final.csv"), index=False)
```

Comment: Arr that looks better, im getting the output `final.csv` but not getting the output formatting correct. I think i need to set the delimiter to `,`.  O yes wanted to add all files are correct and are csvs only but I think my logic must have been wrong. Yours on the other hand is spot on, just need to work out how to set the delimiter and i think i will be sorted.

Comment: hmm according to docs default delimiter is `,` so not sure whats going on there

Comment: Use the `sep` keyword argument for specifying the delimiter , but delimiter by default is `,` . What formatting are you getting the data in? Maybe the delimiter is actually something else?

Comment: nope its `,` just checked. Also the output is adding another column that looks to be an id column. Ill add the data to my post

Comment: Arr yes columns gone, ill try specify the delimiter and see what happens. brb

Comment: hmm how very annoying, even after specifying the delimiter of `,` i still get the wrong output

Comment: The input data does have special characters in it like `[` and `]` would that make any difference?

Comment: hmm, not sure, can you add a few example data in your question? I will try it out

Comment: I have added the relevant data set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89937/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-inoob).

Comment: Use df_list = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in file_list]  instead of pd.read_table(file) for any formating use you get. Thanks.